# PHP SQL query via OCI8 fetching only 1 row when there is more

Tags: php, sql, oracle-call-interface

I am running a very simple query that when I run it in SQL developer I get 3 rows returned but only get 1 row returned when I take the same query and try to retrieve results via OCI_FETCH.

Here is the raw query that when ran in SQL developer it returns 3 distinct rows:

```
select a.cache_nm, b.nm_tx,
CASE
WHEN CAST(max(a.creation_tmstmp) as DATE) - CAST(max(a.request_from_tmstmp) as DATE) < 1/96
THEN 'Current'
ELSE 'BEHIND'
END as Site_Status
from perf_stats a inner join site b on (a.site_seq_id = b.site_seq_id) 
group by a.cache_nm, b.nm_tx
```

;

here is the PHP implementation:

```
// Prepare the statement
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select a.cache_nm, b.nm_tx, 
CASE
    WHEN CAST(max(a.creation_tmstmp) as DATE) - CAST(max(a.request_from_tmstmp) as DATE) < 1/96
    THEN \'Current\'
    ELSE \'BEHIND\'
    END as Site_Status
    from perf_stats a inner join site b on (a.site_seq_id = b.site_seq_id) 
    group by a.cache_nm, b.nm_tx');


    if (!$stid) {
        $e = oci_error($conn);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // Perform the logic of the query
    $r = oci_execute($stid);
    if (!$r) {
        $e = oci_error($stid);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // Fetch the results of the query       
    $nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);

    echo "$nrows rows fetched<br>\n";
    var_dump($res);
```

The resulting page displays:

```
1 rows fetched

array(3) {
    ["CACHE_NM"] => array(1) {
        [0]=> string(13) "SITE-01"
    }
    ["NM_TX"] => array(1) {
        [0]=> string(14) "SITE GAT"
    }
    ["SITE_STATUS"] => array(1) {
        [0] => string(6) "BEHIND"
    }
}
```

I have done many tests breaking down this query and getting multiple rows returned WITHOUT using a group by statement. I have also tried all of the different OCI_FETCH functions.

My question is, do I need to do anything in particular with an OCI8 function in order to use the group by in SQL statements. This is just frustrating as literally the only thing I change in the SQL is the escape clause for the single quotes, and the fact that it is INDEED working, just only for 1 row...